# What is the significance of the Stone Angel?

Tags: kurt-vonnegut, cats-cradle

In Vonnegut's *Cat's Cradle*, there is one scene that I found a bit puzzling.

At the store by the cemetery where Frank and Emily Hoenikker are buried, Jonah's taxi driver becomes obsessed with a stone angel.

The store owner, Marvin Breed, explains that it isn't for sale, and relates the story of why it is still in the store:

> "It was never *paid* for. The way the story goes: this German 
>   immigrant was on his way West with his wife, and she died of 
>   smallpox here in Ilium. So he ordered this angel to be put up over 
>   her, and he showed my great-grandfather he had the cash to pay for 
>   it. But then he was robbed. Somebody took practically every cent 
>   he had. All he had left in this world was some land he'd bought in 
>   Indiana, land he'd never seen. So he moved on--said he'd be back 
>   later to pay for the angel."
>
> "But he never came back?" I asked.
>
> "Nope." Marvin Breed nudged some of the boughs aside with his 
>   toe so that we could see the raised letters on the pedestal. There 
>   was a last name written there. "There's a screwy name for you," he 
>   said. "If that immigrant had any descendants, I expect they 
>   Americanized the name. They're probably Jones or Black or Thompson 
>   now."
>
> "There you're wrong," I murmured.
>
> The room seemed to tip, and its walls and ceiling and floor 
>   were transformed momentarily into the mouths of many tunnels--
>   tunnels leading in all directions through time. I had a Bokononist 
>   vision of the unity in every second of all time and all wandering 
>   mankind, all wandering womankind, all wandering children.
>
> "There you're wrong," I said, when the vision was gone.
>
> "You know some people by that name?"
>
> "Yes."
>
> The name was my last name, too.

Clearly this is a strange and powerful moment for the narrator.  Yet I don't recall it being mentioned again, except perhaps in passing.

What is the significance of this?  More importantly, what is the name on the angel (I don't believe the narrator ever gives his last name)?  Does Vonnegut ever explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name on the gravemarker has often been postulated as "Vonnegut", for example in this critique [here](http://us.macmillan.com/newcriticalessaysonkurtvonnegut/DavidSimmons) in New Critical Essays on Kurt Vonnegut.

> By not directly naming the "screwy" German surname, Vonnegut
>   introduces the possibility that the name on the stone is "Vonnegut", a
>   screwy German name. The plausibility of this assumption is confirmed
>   by the fact that Vonnegut originally planned to name the narrator
>   "Vonnegut", but the editor talked him out of it.

As for its significance, it's probably a foreshadowing of the narrator's own death (possibly to Ice 9) as exemplified by your quote above starting with "The room seemed to tip..." The novel is full of imagery of death / dying / gravestones.

Comment: The land in Indiana is another hint, Vonnegut being a member of the Hoosier granfalloon.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned again - in a strange passage when he's deciding whether or not to accept the presidency of San Lorenzo:

> And the time of the night and the cave and the waterfall--and the stone angel in Ilium....
>   And 250,000 cigarettes and 3,000 quartz of booze, and two wives and no wife....
>
> And no loving for me anywhere....
>
> And the listless life of an ink-stained hack....
>
> And Pabu, the moon, and Borasisi, the sun, and their children....
>
> All things conspired to form one cosmic vin-dit, one mighty shove into Bokononism, into the belief that God was running my life and that he had work for me to do.

I see two interpretations:

1. Some ancestor of his purchased a *stone angel* for him that was never claimed such that he ends up inheriting its divine get-out-of-jail-free card when he's saved by a phantom stomach ache and the patch of stone to which it drives him.
2. The incredible coincidence leads him to believe that powers beyond his comprehension are at work and he should just go along with them and accept this unexpected presidency.

Maybe both.